# Flex Parsley - How to include ActionScript File in Configuration

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex3, parsley

I am trying to use Parsley framework on my application. I am able to include all my custom components (`written in mxml`) and other mxml files in Parsley's configuration file like this,

```
<components:Panel1/>
<components:Panel2/>
```

etc ..

But, I have some `actionscript` files, that have a constructor **expecting a mandatory argument**. So, when I try to include that actionscript file in Parsley's Configuration file, it shows me an error like below ..
e.g `CustomPanel.as`

In Parsley's config file ..

```
<components:Panel1/>
<components:Panel2/> 
.
.
<custom:CustomPanel/>    // Error line ..
```

> **Error :1136: Incorrect number of arguments.  Expected 1.**

So, my question is,

> How to include such ActionScript files,which have a necessary argument
>   in its constructor, in Parsley's configuration file, so that I can use
>   that actionscript file in Parsley's messaging system.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure...
But this should be a problem...

Your **CustomPanel.as** class will be required one argument in CustomPanel constructor...

When we are adding any class to in our **MXML** parsley context, it will create its object.
So one argument is required for creating your CustomPanel class object.

So it is giving error....